# How to install image ImageMagick on Heroku php build

Tags: php, heroku, imagemagick

How do you install ImageMagick on Heroku with a PHP build? The PHP version on Heroku is PHP `7.0.01`, and from what I know ImageMagick doesn't support that version.

Comment: If ImageMagick doesn't support it, then you can't install it. Your car key's don't go into your house door's lock, so what do you do now? Force them into the lock?

Comment: Are you talking about Imagemagick or Imagick?

Comment: I'm talking about imagick @Bonzo